# Laravel Scout how refresh index with ElasticSearch?

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-5.3

I'm working on a Laravel project and I'm using https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout with ElasticSearch on a model `Offer`.

I already have some offers in my database, so I just run the command

```
 `php artisan scout:import "App\Models\Offer"`
```

for generate the index for use my datas with ElasticSearch.

After that it's ok, I can search in my offers with, for example :

```
 `$offers = Offer::search($request->keywords)->get();`
```

Now I have a function for create other offers in my database, and I dont know how can I refresh the index for use these new datas ?

In the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scout#adding-records, I can read

> all you need to do is save a model instance and it will automatically be added to your search index

I tried this and no, when I save() a new Offer, I can't find it in my index.

I tried to re run the command `php artisan scout:import "App\Models\Offer"` after add anew OFfer, but it's the same, I can't find it in my index.

Did I miss something ? Any ideas ?

Comment: You have `use`d the `Searchable` trait in your model, right?

Comment: Yep I have this trait in my model Offer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for a late response on this but I ran into this issue myself when I attempted to use Scout. Everything went fine until I realized that the project's data would scale at a rate that went far beyond what scout could handle. In this case, however you can use the `push()` method instead of `save()`. I'm not sure why this isn't documented at all and it's rather frustrating but there's an answer at least.

So use:

`->push()`

instead of:

`->save()`

to update your indexes.
If that does not work for your specific version there is another way you can do it but it is "slightly" redundant. It involves a mix of using the queue system with the `Artisan` system and a command. In this you:

- Create a queue/job `php artisan make:job JobNameHere` **(As of Laravel 5.2 - 5.4)**
- Add `use Artisan;` to the top of that newly created Job Class so you can pull in the Artisan's functionality
- In the handle of that Job Class add

  ```
  class JobNameHere implements ShouldQueue {

     ...
     ...

     public function handle() {
         Artisan::call('scout:import', ['name' => "App\YourModelNameHere"]);
     }
  }
  ```
- Add a dispatch call to that job class right after your DB `push()` process is called. 
  Example:

  ```
  class YourController extends Controller {

      public function yourUpdateMethod(Request $request) {

          //Some code you wrote
          //Some more code you wrote

          $update_obj->push( $array_to_update_obj);
          dispatch(new JobNameHere());
      }
  }
  ```
- Test your index by searching on it

If all went well then you should no longer get any errors. Please leave a comment and let me know how it went... provided you're still having this issue.

I would also like to mention that Laravel Scout does not support ElasticSearch anymore as of August of 2016 (I believe). No one really knows why the support was removed but there are a few tutorials out there to help you get Laravel and Elastic search working together again.

I will also note, based on my research, that if your project is small then you should be fine to use Scout and not need to use ElasticSearch. If your project is going to get huge, then you're probably better off finding a package that supports and well documents how handle Laravel's relationships between models. Elastic search is capable of accomplishing this but there are tons of docs that make figuring it out difficult. Here are some semi-decent tutorials to help get you going down the right path.

https://tirdeamihai.com/blog/laravel-and-elasticsearch

https://laravel-news.com/laravel-and-elasticsearch

**Plastic is a package that I would currently recommend as it's being actively worked on. Elasticquent hasn't been touched or updated since last year in June.**
https://github.com/sleimanx2/plastic#1---create-a-new-index